# Accidently discarded lollipop update on nexus 4

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have accidently cancelled android update ffrom tasks. Now how will I get it again?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but go to Settings > About phone > System updates, then see whether there is an update, or press "Check now".

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I delayed upgrading my Nexus4 to Android L and now the option seems to have disappeared. I was going with the theory that Google decided there were too many bugs and removed the OTA update

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel an update, you can almost always go back and still update the phone. All you need to do go to Settings >>>> About Phone >>>> System Updates >>>> And then click "Check for Updates" or "Check Now"

Comment: I did it almost 100 times in a day. But it is saying System updated and showing version 4.4